# React Drop Down does not update value when chosen

Tags: reactjs

This is my problem ( I did not reported all the code, just some extracts)

```
class Country extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        countryList: [], //( I wrote a method to obtain country list)
        selectedCountry: ''        
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event){
    this.setState({
      selectedCountry: event
    });
    console.log(this.state.selectedCountry);
  }


<Select className="select2-selection react-select select2-selection--multiple" placeholder="Select country" value={this.state.selectedCountry} classNamePrefix="react-select" options={this.state.countryList} onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event)} />
```

The matter is , at the first choice ex France, `selectedCountry` is empty, when I choose ex Italy, the value is France, when I choose Germany, the value is Italy etc ..

I read that the state is asynchronous and tried some suggested solutions but couldn't solve, any ideas?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atHad.png)

Comment: Can you tell me if you are using `select-2` or `react-select`?

Comment: import Select from 'react-select';

Comment: From the classes you are using in `Select` it seems you are using `select2` library.
You should check if there is any `select2` library used in your project `public/index.html` I believe that is conflicting with the `react-select`

Comment: yes in idex html I am using select2, what is the correct import?

Comment: Then, in this case you need to avoid using `select2-selection select2-selection--multiple ` classes in `Select` as they are used under the hood by `select2`.

Comment: Done but issue still present

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`setState` supports a second argument, which is a callback method that will be called after the state is set.

So

```
handleChange(event){
  this.setState({
    selectedCountry: event
  }, function(){
    console.log(this.state.selectedCountry);
  });
}
```

Comment: Hello, I added your code but  unfortunately still not working

Comment: The value does not update with the correct value, if I choose Country-X, I see in console the Country-Y I 've chosen before

Comment: @user18363545 please post a live example so we can see it in action.

Comment: Hello, I noticed that at every selection there is an undefined selection ( see image above)

Comment: @user18363545 it works as expected at https://codesandbox.io/s/new-night-olofg0?file=/src/App.js so that other log must be coming from some other part of your code.